# Equivalent color settings in Blender with Autodesk Navisworks

Tags: materials, color

I want to get the equivalent color settings in Blender by comparing RGB values in Autodesk Navisworks color properties from Material tab when an object has been selected.

Here are the color properties values from Autodesk Navisworks:

[image: Color properties in Autodesk Navisworks]

So far I have managed to achieve the equivalent color settings in Blender for Diffuse, Specular, and Emissive.

Here are the auto-generated Phyton code by Blender's scripting tool when I change the color in the screenshot below:

[image: Color setting in Material tab]

Python codes generated:

```
bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (0.442353, 0.331765, 0.294118)
bpy.context.object.active_material.specular_color = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
bpy.context.object.active_material.volume.emission_color = (0, 0, 0)
```

Questions:

1. Where can I set the RGB values for Ambient in Blender?
2. How do I adjust the Shininess and Transparency in Blender?

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, Blender has two independent render engines (Blender render - aka internal - and Cycles), and they use different kind of materials, since the first is scanline renderer, and the second is PBR renderer... do you need values for Blender Render? maybe show what values you already set, so people will guess how to answer this better.

Comment: @m.ardito, hi I have added a screenshot in my question. Is my color setting based on Blender Render? If yes, what are the equivalent values I need to provide for other color settings? Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is the Blender Internal Renderer, often called "BI" for short. It may be important for you to know that **all development has stopped for the BI engine.** Any future development will *only* be for the Cycles engine (or the game engine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment above: yes, you're using Blender Render.

About 1)

Ambient color should be what is set in the World settings, here:

[image]

And you can level the amount of ambient each material gets with this:

[image]

see also 
https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/introduction.html

About 2) I think you need to set your material's specular:

You can choose color, intensity, shader type, and you can also use a custom-defined color ramp, if needed, here:

[image]

See whole reference here: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/index.html

Of course, being Blender Internal a scanline renderer, it is not targeted to ultra-realistic results.

I don't know Navisworks at all, so it could be a similar system, or not. Maybe others will help better than me in this respect.

Blender's Cycles, instead, is a very good PBR renderer and it allows ultra realistic results, if needed, but its materials are completely different, and based on nodes - in that case, start here: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/index.html

Comment: Yeah, it's more or less what I figured. I don't think you can set "ambient color" per materials in Blender, since the color of the ambient is taken from the scene's world settings. These type of settings are very tied to rendering system they belong to, and ambient color is probably used to fake some sort of global illumination in real time rendering not really needed or wanted in pre-calculated renders