# Where is emission color in Cycles Render Engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, color

with reference to my previous post ([Equivalent color settings in Blender with Autodesk Navisworks](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52697/equivalent-color-settings-in-blender-with-autodesk-navisworks)), I am changing the render engine from Blender Render to Cycles Render.

I could not find the settings for Emissive color in Cycles Render.

I managed to find Emissive color in Blender Render:

[image: Emissive Color in Blender Render]

I have searched for Emissive color in [Cycles Render Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/index.html), but to no avail.

Where can I set the Emissive Color in Cycles Render?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cycles Render you find the emissive material by 
a) > Properties Editor > Material > Surface > Use Nodes > Surface Emission or more easily:
b) within the Node Editor by > Shift+A > Shader > Emission. Connect this to the Surface input of the Material Output node.

Or give this Add-On a try:
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Material/Blender_Cycles_Materials_Converter

Comment: Hi @HTT, in method (a), I could not find "Surface Emission" in "Use Nodes" Menu. My Blender version is 2.77a. The closest match is "Emission". It shows my color for "Diffuse BSDF" before I begin method (a).

Comment: That's the normal way. The first material to show up when you select "use nodes" is the "Surface: (Text on the left) Diffusive BDSF (Box with a dot on the right)". Click on the right one and from the pop up window choose the "Emission". Set your desired color and the strength you need. Strength means a kind of multiplier to rise the impact of the color without the need to change the initial color values.